# WCF test utility can't get metadata and why ref not supported

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I had simple WCF service running in ASP website. I decided to create page and make call from JavaScript. According to [description I found](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627082/How-to-Consume-WCF-Service-using-JavaScript-Proxy) that I need to create service that generates proxy classes. I have changed web.config:

web config before:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

      <services>
        <service name="fmNVBwebSrv.fmNVBDevice">
       </service>
      </services>      


    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

web.config after:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="fmNVBwebSrv.WCFJSproxyBehavior">
              <enableWebScript/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>

            <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="MEX">
                <serviceMetadata/>
              </behavior>

              <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

      <services>
        <service name="fmNVBwebSrv.fmNVBDevice">
          <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="fmNVBwebSrv.WCFJSproxyBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" contract="fmNVBwebSrv.IFmNVBDevice">
          </endpoint>
        </service>

        <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MEX">
          <endpoint
              address="http://localhost:8200/MEX"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>


      </services>      


    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And now WCF Test Client utility shows error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:35168/fmNVB.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.

And if I go to site using browser by entering adders  http://localhost:35168/fmNVB.svc I have error:

```
Operation 'GetErrorByCode' in contract 'IFmNVBDevice' specifies an 'out' or 'ref' parameter. Operations with 'out' or 'ref' parameters are not supported.
```

That is actually true, because `GetErrorByCode` has parameter that contains `ref`. But why it is not allowed and how to fix problem with WCF test utility?

Comment: You simply cannot have `ref` and `out` parameters in operations. How do you expect a HTTP-service to receive something using `ref`? Just imagine it :)

Comment: I expect service to return something to caller using ref. I can't imagine since I new in web services, but this looks normal by looking from remote function call perspective. Does it means I can't use ref in any type of web services? But why first version of web.config allows call functions using WCF test utility?

Comment: A web-service is located in another context. It knows nothing about any variables in a caller's context. So, when a client calls WCF method, it actually serializes a message (SOAP, XML, JSON etc.) and sends it over HTTP. Then, server returns serialized message and client deserializes it. Roughly speaking, it passes it by value. There is no way to pass a reference to a variable in client's context to a server.

Comment: But I expect JavaSript to wokt like WCF utility. WCF test utility is happy regarding my web service interface functions has ref parameter.